# Laravel: How to return JSON response when using foreach

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am uploading images using Vue and my Laravel backend endpoint looks like this below.  I am unsure of what to put in the response though since it is a `foreach` that iterates through each file and uploads them but I still want to return the response as JSON.

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $files = $request->file('images');

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        Storage::put('store/assets/', file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()), ['visibility' => 'public']);
    }

    return response()->json(????);
}
```

Comment: Is there anything in particular that you want to do with the response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $files = $request->file('images');
    $stack = [];
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $fileName = Storage::put('store/assets/', file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()),
            ['visibility' => 'public']);
        array_push($stack, $fileName);
    }

    return response()->json($stack);
}
```

Or you can just do like that:

```
$data = ["success" => 1];

return response()->json($data);
```

My offer:
if your query is executed succesfully
        `$data=[
          "stat"=>1,
          "data"=>[
              "first"=>1,
              ...
           ]
        ]`
else
        `$data=[
            "stat"=>0,
            "error"=>"Not successfull"
         ]`

Comment: If I went with the approach `$data = ["success" => 1];` , where would I put it and how would I catch an error to send a different response if it didn't go through successfully?